# Corrupt NTFS partition's MFT – Which tool is right? What tool to fix?

Tags: ntfs, gparted, testdisk, ntfs-3g, mft

I used Avira Rescue Disk (Ubuntu 12.04) to access a broken NTFS boot partition. Windows 7 fails to mount it: it displays a bluescreen ("UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME") and restarts immediately. With the Rescue Disk I could backup the most important data (Ubuntu does *not* fail on mounting). Now I tried `gparted` to fix the partition. To analyse the partition, gparted runs a scanning-only `ntfsresize` first.

A similar (= non-writing) but manual run of `ntfsresize -info --force /dev/sda3` gives:

```
ntfsresize v2012.1.15AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name        : /dev/sda3
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 484336226816 bytes (484337 MB)
Current device size: 484336230400 bytes (484337 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
  0,00 percent completed
..
..
..
 12,83 percent completed
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
Failed to read of MFT, mft=73604 count=1 br=-1: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler (= I/O error)
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
Failed to read of MFT, mft=73605 count=1 br=-1: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
Failed to read of MFT, mft=73606 count=1 br=-1: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
Failed to read of MFT, mft=73607 count=1 br=-1: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
 12,85 percent completed
..
..
..   
 100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Cluster accounting failed at 9962391 (0x980397): extra cluster in $Bitmap
..
..
..   
Cluster accounting failed at 9963113 (0x980669): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Filesystem check failed! Totally 723 cluster accounting mismatches.
ERROR: NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
and will be made to NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.
```

So, the $MFT seems to be broken. However, `ntfsfix --no-action /dev/sda3` (non-writing) states:

```
avira@avira:~$ sudo ntfsfix -n /dev/sda3
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sda3 was processed successfully.
```

Whom can I trust? What really happened to my $MFT? Why can Ubuntu still read most of the files, and Win 7 fails to mount (expect from *being* Windows)? What tool should I use to fix the MFT: `gparted` or `testdisk` or `ntfsfix` (without `--no-action`) or `chkdsk /f`? Haven't felt lucky yet. I've read about `testdisk` being able to mess up $MFT and $MFTMirr in severe cases. Could that happen?

Additionally, SMART reports one bad sector (Reallocated Sectors Count = 1). Should I renew the disk in any event?

What can I run else to (at least) locate the error (e.g. affected filenames, electromechanical failure y/n?) better?

Comment: Your hdd failed your MFT was on the corrupted sector.

Comment: @Ramhound Obviously, yes. What next? Should I try `chkdsk /r`?

Comment: TestDisk will be the savior, read its documentation and do the actions carefully.

Comment: Linux doesn't have a (free) equivalent of Window's chkdsk. That's why it's suggested for use by the Linux utilities you used. I don't see where you followed those suggestions . . .

Answer (score 2):

If the MFT$ file got corrupted, try [R-STUDIO](http://www.r-studio.com) to rescue the data on that drive.

**Important: Do not perform any write operation to the corrupted drive!**

1. attach the corrupted drive to a working windows system
2. analyze the drive using r-studio
3. copy any good data to a new drive
4. delete all partitions on the corrupted drive ("old drive")
5. create a new partition on the old drive and format
6. use a tool of your choice to analyze the drives hardware, if required.

Done!